# What is the quickest way to compile and run any single C file

Tags: c, makefile, emacs, spacemacs

I'd like to compile and run a single c source file on a keypress such as `<F5>`, now I've looked at several ways of accomplishing this and most involve using a Makefile. However, every example I've found on a generic Makefile require editing the TARGET or compiling all source files in the working directory. This led me to the question if I could run a regexp and replace the first line of the Makefile from any source file I'm working on.

1. Press `<F5>`

   1. Update Makefile in root projectdir with current `<file>`.c working on.
   2. Run make ONLY on `<file>`

There may be a simpler way of accomplishing this without editing the Makefile, but I've exhausted myself with trying to make a generic enough makefile to do it.

The regexp I have that would select the correct line:

```
^TARGET\s[=]\s.*
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem really. So each single one of your C files is also a full program? What do you need a Makefile for then?

Comment: I'm working through K&R, I'm just trying to automatically compile and run the examples and exercises I'm working on without having to leave emacs or type `gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic -O3 <file> -o <file>` everytime

Comment: `-ansi` :( isn't your problem "how to compile run a single C file without writing the command", not "how to edit a line in a file"

Comment: I'd like to know both really.

Comment: This is actually an interesting question. The interesting part is writing an emacs macro that can invoke Make, and the small technical part is binding this macro to <F5>.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `.dir-locals.el` file in your project directory with something like:

```el
((c-mode . ((eval . (setq-local compile-command
                                (format "gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror %s"
                                        (shell-quote-argument (file-name-nondirectory
                                                               buffer-file-name))))))))
```

Then you can just bind <kbd><f5></kbd> to `compile` and it will do the appropriate thing.

Making `compile` do "the right thing" means that you can consistently use the same command in all projects whenever you need to compile (or perform any vaguely analogous activity, depending on what the current project happens to be).

Answer (score 1):

For testing small programs, I often use this bash script that cleans up after itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror $1 -o tempout &&\
    ./tempout && rm tempout
```

I have this saved in an executable file called `crepl`, and I can use it by entering at the command line:

```
> crepl my_program.c
```

I use the `-Werror` flag so that code with warnings will not execute. This is pretty primitive, and won't work when libraries must be linked, but it is useful for simple small programs.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I'm way overcomplicating things. I'll accept this once I figure out how to pass `(file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))` as an argument executing a shell script from emacs.

Answer (score 1):

I use [multi-compile](https://github.com/ReanGD/emacs-multi-compile).  Here's my config:

```
(use-package multi-compile
  :config
  (defun locate-repo-dir (&optional file-or-dir)
    "Find the root of the version control repository."
    (let* ((file-or-dir (or file-or-dir (buffer-file-name) default-directory))
           (file-dir (if (file-directory-p file-or-dir)
                         file-or-dir
                       (file-name-directory file-or-dir)))
           (root-dir (vc-call-backend (vc-deduce-backend) 'root file-dir)))
      root-dir))

  (dolist (e '(("%cflags" . (or (getenv "CFLAGS") "-Wall -g3 -std=c11"))
               ("%cxxflags" . (or (getenv "CXXFLAGS") "-Wall -g3"))
               ("%repo-dir" . (locate-repo-dir))))
    (add-to-list 'multi-compile-template e))

  (setq multi-compile-alist
        '((".*" . (("make-simple" .
                    "make -k")
                   ("make-repo" .
                    "make -k --no-print-directory -C '%repo-dir'")
                   ("make-top" .
                    "make -k --no-print-directory -C '%make-dir'")))
          (c-mode . (("c-simple" .
                      "gcc -o '%file-sans' %cflags '%file-name'")
                     ("c-simple32" .
                      "gcc -o '%file-sans' %cflags -m32 '%file-name'")))
          (c++-mode . (("c++-simple" .
                        "g++ -o '%file-sans' %cxxflags '%file-name'")))))

  :bind (("C-c b" . multi-compile-run))
  )
```

The c-simple option is exactly what I use for single-file C programs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of a function I bind to <kbd>C-c C-C</kbd> in my `c-mode-map`. It just compiles the file, runs it with output to the compilation buffer, and then removes the compiled program. Note that you can string together multiple shell commands in your `compile-command` to run/cleanup etc. With a prefix it will prompt for compilation command as normal.

```
(defun my-compile-and-run (arg)
  "Compile, run (output to compilation buffer), remove program."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((out (concat (file-name-sans-extension
                       (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))))
         (command
          (concat "gcc -std=c11 "       ;other flags, etc.
                  buffer-file-name " -o " out
                  "; ./" out            ;run executable
                  "; rm " out)))        ;clean up
    (unless arg
      (setq-local compilation-read-command nil))
    (setq-local compile-command command)
    (call-interactively 'compile)))
```

You can get more creative with your `compile-command` as well. If you actually wanted to run it through a makefile, for example,

```
CURRENT ?=
EXE     = $(CURRENT:.c=)

target: ${CURRENT}
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic -O3 ${CURRENT} -o ${EXE}

run-target: target
    ${EXE}

clean-target:
    $(RM) ${EXE}
```

You could then compile from emacs by just setting the `compile-command` to set the `CURRENT` variable to the buffers name and call whichever make targets you want, eg.

```
(defun my-compile-and-run (arg)
  "Compile, run (output to compilation buffer), remove program."
  (interactive "P")
  (when (file-exists-p "Makefile")
    (let ((command (concat "make CURRENT=\"" ;set current target
                           (shell-quote-argument buffer-file-name)
                           ;run and clean program
                           "\" run-target clean-target"))) 
      (unless arg
        (setq-local compilation-read-command nil))
      (setq-local compile-command command)
      (call-interactively 'compile))))
```

Typically you want to set the `compile-command` in you mode-hooks or as a local variable like @phils shows in the .dirs-locals.el or the other alternative ways to define emacs local variables.